# How to select just the row in the second table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with an ID:

```
--FIRST TABLE--
| IDCLIENT |    DATE    |
   112102    2013-10-11
```

The table below will always have an ID of the first table.

```
--SECOND TABLE--
| IDCLIENT | VALUE | OTHERCOLUMNS
   112102     50
   112103     30
```

But this other table may not have the ID of the first table.

```
--THIRD TABLE--
| IDCLIENT | VALUE | OTHERCOLUMNS
   112102     10
```

If the ID is just on the second table I want to select that row. If the ID is in both tables, I want to select just the row on the third table. How can I achieve that? I tried using joins but without success.

**UPDATE**

I want to SUM() the values on the VALUE column.

Comment: Can you provide the query that you tried?

Comment: For me it is not clear how many tables do you have, and which one is the first one, the second one and the third one.

Comment: "If the ID is just on the second table I want to select that row. If the ID is in both tables, I want to select just the row on the second table." Does it mean that you want to select row from second table in both cases ?

Comment: *If the ID is just on the second table I want to select that row. If the ID is in both tables, I want to select just the row on the second table* -> Isn't that the same?

Comment: So you want to select **never** from the third table?

Comment: I made a little mistake :) I updated the question.

Comment: @erickalves05: Edited my answer according to your last edit. You want a single value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use a case statement for the value. Below is just off the top of my head, so you may need to use full join if that doesn't work.

```
select t1.date, case when t3.IDCLIENT is not NULL then t3.value else t2.value end as Value
from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2 on t1.IDCLIENT = t2.IDCLIENT inner join
Table3 t3 on t1.IDCLIENT = t3.IDCLIENT
```

Comment: Just changed to FULL JOIN and everything worked great. Thank you very much.

Comment: This query returns the wrong result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1ec35/4/0 (should be 10+20+40).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a typo at *"If the ID is just on the **second** table I want to select that row. If the ID is in both tables, I want to select just the row on the **second** table"*. That would mean that you want to select always from the second table and never from the third.

So i guess that you want to select from the third if there is an matching ID, otherwise use the second as "fallback"-table.

You can use `EXISTS` with `CASE`:

```
SELECT t1.IDCLIENT,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table3 t3 
                       WHERE t3.IDCLIENT = t1.IDCLIENT)
       THEN (SELECT TOP 1 t3.Value FROM dbo.Table3 t3 
             WHERE t3.IDCLIENT = t1.IDCLIENT)
       ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Value FROM dbo.Table2 t2
             WHERE t2.IDCLIENT = t1.IDCLIENT)
       END AS Value
FROM dbo.Table1 t1
```

> I want to SUM() the values on the VALUE column.

Then you can use a subquery on the query above like:

```
SELECT SUM(X.Value) FROM(
  SELECT t1.IDCLIENT,
         CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table3 t3 
                         WHERE t3.IDCLIENT = t1.IDCLIENT)
         THEN (SELECT TOP 1 t3.Value FROM dbo.Table3 t3 
               WHERE t3.IDCLIENT = t1.IDCLIENT)
         ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Value FROM dbo.Table2 t2
               WHERE t2.IDCLIENT = t1.IDCLIENT)
         END AS Value
  FROM dbo.Table1 t1
) X
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1ec35/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: I didn't know I could make a SUM() in a CASE statement. Well, when I tried your solution I got this error: "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery." But I will keep in your trail. Thanks.

Comment: @erickalves05: Then use a sub-query, edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need to to a LEFT JOIN there.

Read up on it [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208894%28v=office.12%29.aspx)